# How to get the db status using java?

Tags: java, mysql

I am new to the java programing and trying to develop an application. On my jsp page I am allowing user to enter the db details and then click on test button to check whether connection is set or not.

Comment: 1. Try connecting. 2. See whether it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the SQLException from DriverManager.getConnection(). By this you can validate the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no Exception occurred while connecting with the given database details
you can tell connection is success.Else catch the exception and show message accordingly  to the user

Answer (score 0):

you can fire `"select 1"` query using jdbc and if it don't throw any exception than you can say connection is done..